# How to slice an image in gee into multiple images

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to slice a big image into images with shape 256x256xchannels, one of my channels show the class of a pixel, which can be 0, 1 or 2. My goal with this slice is to throw out the images that only have pixels with the class 0, so that when I export those images I would spend less space in memory. How can I do that in the google earth engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `image.updateMask(image.select('class').neq(0))` to mask off the pixels that have the class you don't want.

Then, use one of the two tiled export options:

- `Export.image` with `fileDimensions: 256` to ask for tiles rather than a single image, or
- `Export.map.toCloudStorage` (which exports standard 256×256 web map tiles)

and specify the option `skipEmptyTiles: true`. This will result in not exporting any tiles which are fully masked off.